# Android Release Keystore

Tags: android, release, keystore

I just started wondering if I **MUST** create a Keystore for each Android app I develop considering that our company develops custom made apps for clients. Should I create one Keystore for each app or just one for all of them?

EDIT: Also how many alias for each keystore and if more than one, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are developing apps for clients, you shouldn't really hold the signing keys. Since it's *their* app, they should own the signing keys and publish it. Ideally, you would send them unsigned APKs which they will sign and publish. If they can't/don't want to do that, you should have separate keys for each company. First, because at some point they may require you hand it over, and second to limit the damage if the keystore is lost or damaged.

Also, your question doesn't explicitly say this, but regardless of how manage keystore files, do use different *keys* for each client. Otherwise Client A may get access to Client B's data if the two apps happen to be installed on the same device and use signature-level permissions.

Comment: Thank you, in my case they dont want to sing their apps, so I'll do as you say and create different Aliases for each client.